# Gitlab-CI Kubernetes integration: variables not set

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have an issue with kubernetes variables not set in Gitlab-CI.
There's [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026971/gitlab-ci-kubernetes-variables-arent-set), but it talks about the "old" integration, not the latest that works differently.

So here's the thing. I have a free account, and a kubernetes cluster configured. Everything works fine, the cluster is correctly configured, Helm Tiller, Prometheus and Gitlab-CI-Runner have been installed, and the runner is used to execute the jobs.

Since it's a free account, I can add only one cluster with a `*` scope, and [the documentation](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/clusters/index.md#setting-the-environment-scope-premium) says that the following variables should be available through any job:

KUBE_URL
KUBE_TOKEN
KUBE_NAMESPACE
KUBE_CA_PEM_FILE
KUBE_CA_PEM
KUBECONFIG

But none of them are set, the following job echoes nothing, except the CI_PROJECT_ID:

```
build_backend:
  stage: build
  except: [ tags ]
  script:
    - echo CI_PROJECT_ID=$CI_PROJECT_ID
    - echo KUBE_URL=$KUBE_URL
    - echo KUBE_CA_PEM_FILE=$KUBE_CA_PEM_FILE
    - echo KUBE_TOKEN=$KUBE_TOKEN
    - echo KUBE_NAMESPACE=$KUBE_NAMESPACE
    - echo KUBE_CA_PEM=$KUBE_CA_PEM
    - echo KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG
```

I was not able to find any lead (except the obsolete issue referenced above), but as it's quite recente, I could not make the difference between *it has not been tested yet* or *I'm the only one having the issue*

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026971/gitlab-ci-kubernetes-variables-arent-set

Comment: This is the issue referenced in mine, but the solution does not work in my case on gitlab.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I can confirm this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026971/gitlab-ci-kubernetes-variables-arent-set#) and that the provided solution does indeed work.

Add this to your job:

```
  environment: 'production'
```

`production` being the name of an environment (you can create it before in the dedicated screen, but it's not necessary).

Comment: I already did this, but the variables aren't set. That's why I thought it was a different issue. I'll try with the ' to see if it has an impact...